# end Kernel Panic (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel

I'm new to Ubuntu, so you'll have to forgive my naivety.

I was watching TV online and my laptop froze (Screen darkened, nothing responding), I left it for around 5 minutes hoping it'd sort itself out. After the 5 minutes nothing was happening so I held down the power button to turn it off.

When I came to turn it on again, the screen changed from its usual purple to black and presented me with a hell of a lot of info and finally leaving me with this message:

```
[   10.489975] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing : Attempted to kill init! exit code=0x00000100
```

Here are the messages immediately preceding the kernel panic:

```
[ 10.441578] Call Trace: 
[ 10.441628] [<c168f1d4>] dump_stack +0x41/0x52 
[ 10.441675] [<c16893e6>] panic+0x87/0x1a5 
[ 10.441723] [<c105edef?] do_exit +0x8df/0x8e0 
[ 10.441771] [<c118f344>] ? vfs_write+0x144/0x1d0 
[ 10.441818] [<c105ee26>] SyS_exit +0x16/0x20 
[ 10.441866] [<c1696649>] syscall_call+0x7/0x7 
[ 10.441922] Kernel Offset : 0x0 from 0xc1000000 (relocation range: 0xc00000000-0xf7ffdfff)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: The really interesting error messages, in this case, are the ones immediately preceding the Kernel panic message. Do you still have those?

Comment: Here's what appears immediately before:

[    10.441578] Call Trace:
[    10.441628]  [<c168f1d4>] dump_stack +0x41/0x52
[    10.441675]  [<c16893e6>] panic+0x87/0x1a5
[    10.441723]  [<c105edef?] do_exit +0x8df/0x8e0
[    10.441771]  [<c118f344>] ? vfs_write+0x144/0x1d0
[    10.441818]  [<c105ee26>] SyS_exit +0x16/0x20
[    10.441866]  [<c1696649>] syscall_call+0x7/0x7
[    10.441922] Kernel Offset : 0x0 from 0xc1000000 (relocation range: 0xc00000000-0xf7ffdfff)

Comment: From similar questions, this could be a hardware problem, or it could be nothing at all. When you restart the laptop, does it panic at the same point each time?